# Break point in release mode

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I am using (C++) Visual Studio 2010.

I have to trace the control flow of my Application. To do so, I have put a break point in the source code.

While running the app in Debug mode, the break point hits. But in Release mode it didn't hit.

How can I cause the break point to be hit when debugging in Release mode?

Comment: No way. That's (one of the reasons) what debug mode actually is for. Why do you want to hit breakpoint in release mode?

Comment: "Release" mode enables optimizations that can (and frequently do) disrupt the flow of your code. It's very hard to watch a problem occur with optimizations enabled, that's why they're not enabled in "Debug" mode. Programmers generally use that to do their debugging. Do you not see the problem you're trying to solve in Debug mode?

Comment: And the programming language is?

Comment: The programming language is irrelevant. They all support optimizations that potentially alter the program flow. The "Debug" mode is there for a reason and the name wasn't drawn from a hat.

Comment: @Cody: Optimizations make debugging harder, but they do not completely prevent from hitting a breakpoint. Not generating debug info/ rogram database for C++ builds - on the contrary - does prevent.

Comment: Yes, not generating debugging info for a build in *any* language has that effect. But "Release" mode and the generation of debug information are orthogonal to one another. I don't know what you're driving at. Yes, the question is poor and incomplete, I agree. But it doesn't much matter if this is C++ or VB.NET.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In release mode your code is optimized and that can change the flow of your program. For example, if a function is simple and only called once, the compiler can inline the function in release mode.

Debug mode doesn't have these kind of optimization and is designed for debugging your code.

Answer (score 24):

I'm using VS2015.
after lots of failed solutions I found one that worked for me.
Just uncheck "Enable Just My Code" under Menu->Debug->Options->Debugging->General.
See attached image:
[enable debug in release mode-VS2015](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NB7JI.png)

I really hope this will solve the problem to you :)

Comment: I was having an issue where doing a debug build was giving an LNK1104 fatal error (unable to open the exe). Release was building but stopped on break points. Unchecking this setting has now allowed my debug builds to build. Now both build types stop for break points.

Comment: @user1988918 already unchecked, still cannot hit breakpoint....

Answer (score 8):

You can use the __debugbreak() intrinisic. This is also very handy if you want to break on a specific condition. For example:

```
if (var > LIMIT)
  __debugbreak();
```

Answer (score 6):

Release mode breakpoints are handy to get working.  The simplest way to get it working is to make a call to a function called `release_mode_breakpoint()` in your code.  Then define that function like this:

```
#pragma optimize("", off)
void release_mode_breakpoint()
{
    int put_breakpoint_here = 1;
}
#pragma optimize("", on)
```

You can then put a breakpoint on that int declaration line, and it'll be hit, even in release mode.  Then just step up the stack in the debugger back to the function you actually wanted a breakpoint in.

Don't actually leave that code in your final production release though, as the unoptimized line may prevent the compiler from optimizing the calling code properly.