# C++ FAQ example on inline vs. #define

Tags: c++

There is an example on the FAQ to explain the difference between inline and #define. The code is here
and the link is: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/inline-vs-macros.html

Tried with Visual C++, both `unsafe()` and `unsafe(f())` didn't increase `i` twice. Is there a mistake on the example?

Comment: Post code, not links to code.

Comment: The example doesn't have any output in it - you need to show what you did to show the values. And the example doesn't appear to have any problems at first glance.

Comment: there is a comparison in macro. That comparison calls a function. So it's evaluated twice. By the way that site is well-known to be pretty good, so  you  can trust it. And check all your doubts with debugger

Comment: Link in question is currently broken.... And ***that*** is why you should have paid attention to nhgrif's comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main idea of #define is that it is just a preprocessor directive, meaning that this:

```
#define unsafe(i) ( (i) >= 0 ? (i) : -(i) )
```

will preprocess your code before it is compiled, and will replace the statement

```
unsafe(x++);
```

with the following

```
((x++) >= 0 ? (x++) : -(x++));
```

Everytime x++ is evaluated, x gets incremented.

One possible reason why you have problems with getting this sample code right might be that you compile your code with optimizations that optimize out all the unused / unnecessary code.

If you don't use your x anywhere, then it is considered as unused, hence does not get included into compiled code.

Comment: I believe its -O or -O2. However, if you are just learning, then I would suggest not to bother with those flags. Instead, note that there are two default configurations for your VC++ solution (project), namely Debug and Release. The former does not use optimization, hence I suggest running sample code in Debug, and the latter optimizes using some default optimization techniques, including the one I described above.

Answer (score 0):

Just tested the example, Check [Eric Gopak's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20444557/531122) for the explanation:

```
// A macro that returns the absolute value of i
#define unsafe(i)  \
    ((i) >= 0 ? (i) : -(i))

// An inline function that returns the absolute value of i
inline
int safe(int i)
{
    return i >= 0 ? i : -i;
}

int countCalls = 0;

int f()
{
    return countCalls++;
};

int main()
{
    int x = 0;
    int ans = 0;

    ans = unsafe(x++);   // Error! x is incremented twice
    ans = unsafe(f());   // Danger! f() is called twice

    // x = 2
    // countCalls = 2

    ans = safe(x++);     // Correct! x is incremented once
    ans = safe(f());     // Correct! f() is called once

    // x = 3
    // countCalls = 3

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: strange, i used your code (actual mine is the same) but got x=1 from both unsafe() calls. what compiler are you using? i use visual c++ express 2010. Also what compiler options are you using? All i used were defaults.

Comment: @user3078106 you should get ans=0 because it's post increment but ans=1.

Comment: @user3078106 I use Visual Studio 2013, now I also tested this in 2010 which provides the same result (as I expected). Is it possible that you are running your program in Release mode? Values provided in release mode can not always be trusted. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9224051/531122)

Comment: No, I always test in debug mode.

Comment: I got it. But why uk4321 said "should get ans=0 because it's post increment but ans=1"? Where is the post increment from?

Comment: @user3078106 He probably wants to say that when you are debugging and you are at the point of `ans = unsafe(x++);`, `ans` will have value 0. At the point of `ans = unsafe(f());`, `ans` will have value 1. So in short the second increment of `ans` of the first `unsafe()` function is 'committed' at the second `unsafe()` function