# Enter the Visual Studio debugger via a call in C

Tags: c, visual-studio, debugging

I have a case where I want to enter the debugger by using a function call. I know it exists because I saw a reference to it on MSDN. But I have searched and searched but can't find it now.

So what is the function call from C to enter the debugger?

I'm using Visual Studio Express 2013.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Break point in release mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9224000/break-point-in-release-mode)

Comment: Use the `__debugbreak()` function.

Comment: If possible, clarify your question. A simple [DebugBreak](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679297(v=vs.85).aspx) will trip a debug exception and launch *a* debugger if one is properly registered, but you could equally mean you want a `CreateProcess` setup that launches devstudio, providing it a PID to attach to.

Comment: @AndrewMedico - that link points to a bunch of people telling the OP it is essentially impossible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function you're looking for is [Debug Break](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679297%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). This will cause a breakpoint exception in the current process. If you don't have VS already attached, you'll need to make sure [Just In Time Debugging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hs4b7a6.aspx) is enabled.